# How to mock bean used in transform tag in Camel route

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, mockito

I am new at this. please help me. I am using Mockito. I am looking for how to mock a service used in method property of transform tag. My `beans-test.xml` is

```
<spring:route id="jobRoute" startupOrder="2">
  <spring:from uri="direct:start"/>
  <spring:transform>
  <spring:method ref="camelJobService" method="findByStatus"/>
  </spring:transform>
  <spring:to uri="mock:result"/>
</spring:route>
```

Service bean above always hits database. So test case fails. I have looked and fond that [adviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) can be used but I am unable to use it.

However in my test the service is mocked properly.

My test looks like this

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/beans-test.xml")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class CamelRouteTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
protected ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@Produce(uri = "direct:startA")
protected ProducerTemplate producerTemplate1;

@Autowired
QuartzComponent quartzComponent;

CamelJob camelJob;

@Mock
CamelJobRepository camelJobRepository;

@InjectMocks
CamelJobService camelJobService;

@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    returnCamelJob();
}

@Test
public void testJobWithStatus() throws Exception{
    when(camelJobService.findByStatus()).thenReturn(camelJob);

    resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(camelJobService.findByStatus());

    verify(camelJobService.findByStatus());
    producerTemplate.sendBody(resultEndpoint);

    resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: @PhilippSander My question is how to mock `camelJobService` defined in camel route?